# How to make a regex for a user and password

Tags: regex

I need a regex for mu user and password with the following option like this:

- i need the be alphabetic ,uppercase and lowercase letters in any order.
- i need to be numeric
- and also to limit it to 11 characters

I have one of that i founded online but cant make it to uppercase its letters

```
$pattern="^(?=[a-z0-9]{0,9}$)(?:\d*[a-z]){0,10}\d*$";
```

Comment: Add `A-Z` in there along with the `a-z0-9`?

Comment: Try this: `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,11}$`

Comment: Anubhava this doesnt work at all ?

Comment: What does not work? Test case?

Comment: It is funny to see your `doesnt work at all` statement when you haven't even shown valid/invalid sample strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solving**

Okay, so the reason it isn't working for you is that - I believe, anyway - that you're using `PHP` and so therefore your `pattern` needs to be enclosed with `/.../` to make it work. I'm assuming that you haven't done that considering the pattern appears to be from a separate variable.

**RegEx**

*Originally provided by @anubhava*

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,11}$
^                                                   : Matches the start of the string
 (?=.*[A-Z])                                        : Positive look ahead to check for presence of a uppercase letter
            (?=.*[a-z])                             : Positive look ahead to check for presence of a lowercase letter
                       (?=.*\d)                     : Positive look ahead to check for presence of a number
                               [a-zA-Z\d]{1,11}     : Matches ONLY lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numbers between 1 and 11 times
                                               $    : Matches end of the string
```

**Working Example**

```
$password = 'abcABC123';

echo preg_match("/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,11}$/", $password);

// Output: 1

$password_array = [
    'abcdef',
    'abcDEF',
    'abcdefghiJKL123',
    '111111',
    'AAAAAA',
    'ABC123',
    '1_magical',
    '"special2A',
    '%abcDEF123',
    'ABCabc123',
    'somePass1',
    'Password99',
    'alphaNum1'
];

foreach($password_array as $key=>$password){
    echo "\n{$key} => ";
    echo preg_match("/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,11}$/", $password);
}

/*
  Output:
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
    2 => 0
    3 => 0
    4 => 0
    5 => 0
    6 => 0
    7 => 0
    8 => 0
    9 => 1
    10 => 1
    11 => 1
    12 => 1

*/
```